# Oracle 12c sample schema olaptrain is not importing tables

Tags: schema, oracle12c, dmp

OLAPTRAIN12232009.dmp file is not importing tables into 12c database.I followed the procedure found at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/readme-098894.html.
but the tables are not in c##olaptrain user's tables folder.Any idea would be helpfull to me on how to fix this...thanks

Comment: I got it,the answer is not found yet but my work has been completed with another schema...but any answer to this question would be help full to me even now...thanks

Answer (score -1):

alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;